# Unintentionally Sublime-text different setting for two file

Tags: sublimetext2, indentation, sublimetext

I have problem with sublime tab indent.

I have to file: `reply.php` and `view.php`

[image]

==============================================

**view.php:**

1. Tab indents is replaced with spaces.
2. One tab equals with 2 space.

[image]

==============================================

**reply.php:**

1. Tabs is not replaced with spaces
2. One tab equals 4 spaces.

[image]

==============================================

Why? I want reply.php indent and setting. How I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `View -> Indentation` and make sure that `Tab Width` is set to 4, then click on `Convert Indentation to Tabs`. Double-check the other options there to make sure nothing is set that you don't want, such as `Indent Using Spaces`.

To make sure that PHP files are always displayed with tabs, save the following as `Packages/User/PHP.sublime-settings`:

```json
{
    "tab_size": 4,
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": false
}
```